# Unable to get update data join pattern working on d3.stack data structure

Tags: javascript, d3.js, ecmascript-6

I'm having a lot of trouble updating my stacked column chart. (TL;DR: [there's a fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/u31f9Lec/2/), and the error occurs on line 194-5).

As an example, the data structure created by the `stack` function looks like this:

```
[
  [ [0,5], [0,4], [0,6], [0,3] ], // key: apple 
  [ [5,7], [4,7], [6,7], [3,3] ] // key: banana 
]
```

Imagining that each column represents a vitamin, then an apple would have 5 units of vitimin A, 4 of vitamin B, etc..., and an orange would have 2 units of vitamin A, 3 o vitamin B, etc.

I can create the chart in my es6 class:

```
this.svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "seriesGroup")
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(stack(this.data))
    .enter()
    .append("g")
      .attr("class", (d,i) => { return "series" + i})
    .selectAll("rect")
    .data( (d) => { return d; })
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
      .attr("class", ("bar"))
      .attr("x", (d) => { return this.x(d.data.perception); })
      .attr("y", (d) => { return this.y(d[1]); })
      .attr("height", (d) => { return this.y(d[0])- this.y(d[1]); });
      .attr("width", this.x.bandwidth())
```

That code creates the structure:

```
<g class="seriesGroup">
  <g class="series0> //apple
    <rect class="bar"> 
    ...
   </g>
   <g class="series1"> //banana
   ...
```

But updating it is difficult. If I change the data to zero out the apple series, and call `stack` again, I now have:

```
[
  [ [0,0], [0,0], [0,0], [0,0] ], // key: apple 
  [ [0,2], [0,3], [0,1], [0,0] ] // key: banana 
]
```

Here's my update code:

```
    let seriesGroup = this.svg.selectAll(".seriesGroup")
        .data(stack(newData))
        .attr("class", "seriesGroup updated");

    let series = seriesGroup.enter()
        .selectAll( (d,i) => { console.log(i + " series data is " + d); return ".series" + i })
        .data( (d) => { console.log(d); return d; })
        .enter()
          .attr("class", (d) => { console.log(d); return "series updated2" });

    series.enter()
        .selectAll("rect")
        .data( (d) => { console.log(d); return d; })
          .attr("class", ("bar updated"))
          .transition().duration(this.settings.transitionDuration)
          .attr("y", (d) => {
            console.log("Now setting y to " + this.y(d[1]) + " and height to " + (this.y(d[0]) - this.y(d[1])) + " for data " + d);
            return this.y(d[1]); })
          .attr("height", (d) => { return this.y(d[0])- this.y(d[1]); });
```

Somehow this code/svg structure combination is causing a `TypeError: this.setAttribute is not a function` from the d3 library. The line causing the error is:

```
.attr("class", (d) => { console.log(d); return "series updated2" });
```

Clearly I'm screwing up the data join, but I don't know how. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Look at `series`: you have **three** `enter()` functions, **no** `append()` function and a bunch of `attr()` functions. I have no idea of what you're trying to do here.

Comment: The three enter functions reflect the three levels of the data structure: first `<g class=seriesGroup>` whose data is the entire stack array, second the `<g class=series>` whose data is a single "key" row, third the <rect> whose data is a stacked `[lowerValue,upperValue]` pair from a row. There is no `append()` because the number of svg elements shouldn't change; I'm just trying to change the existing `<rect>` elements' heights. The fiddle link provided shows how it's supposed to work, and how it aborts mid-way through.

Comment: After reading your comment above, I advise you to study what is an "enter" selection and what's the purpose of the `enter()` method. This is a constructive criticism.

Comment: Yes, I didn't understand that the update selection is accessed differently. However, this would have just meant that the chart showed the wrong data - it wasn't the root cause of the error. The error is still occurring in the `let series` block even with the `enter()` selections removed. I believe the error is provoked when `attr` is called, but I don't understand why. I've updated the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u31f9Lec/2/

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of the error here is the bad selector. `selectAll` can't take a mapped anonymous function on data it seems, so this line won't work:

`.selectAll( (d,i) => { return ".series" + i })`

Conceptually I find this a bit odd, since the parent selection `seriesGroup` does already have data bound to it - hopefully someone can comment and explain why that line doesn't work. The solution is to declare each `.seriesN` group as a `.series` class too, and select that.

`.selectAll(".series")`

Then a new data join can be performed, for example:

```
.selectAll(".series")
  .data( (d) => { return d; })
  .attr("class", (d,i) => { return "series updated2 series" + i});
```